# Iteration ID in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk, mtm

I am trying to understand the underlying Team Foundation Server (TFS) databases, and I came across this sentence : The Iterarion ID in the TFSWarehouse is not the same as the iteration ID in the workItem tracking table. What does this mean.

I was able to retrieve the historic versions of a work item, and I believe the revision ID refers to the number of time the test case has been updated. What is the Iteration ID? in my example- the revision Id is 38 in the final row, and the iteration ID is 10 constantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iteration ID is the unique identifier of the Iteration path node that is selected in the Test Case (in your example).

Area Path and Iteration Path are tree structures and each node in these structures has a Unique ID. When a work item is assigned to an area or an iteration it's not the Iteration Path that's stored in the Work Item, but the unique identifier of the node.

That doesn't explain the sentence you came across, but without a source or broader quote I have no idea what that may be referring to.